# Insert Anonymous object in a list of same anonymous type

Tags: linq, anonymous-types

I am creating a anonymous type list using LINQ, and later binding it with a ComboBox. But I want to add an empty item in that list, but its not working.

```
    XNamespace ns = xDocItems.Root.Name.Namespace;
    var items =
    from i in
    xDocItems.Descendants(ns + "insync_navpaymentmethods")
    select new
    {
        code = (string)i.Element(ns + "Code"),
    };
```

Here I am creating anonymous type list from a XElement using LINQ.

```
    items.ToList().Insert(0, new { code = string.Empty });

    //items.ToList().Add(new { code = string.Empty }); //Not working
```

Adding a Blank Item in this list. So a Blank item can be selected by user in combo box.

```
    cmbPaymentMethods.DataSource = items.ToList();
    cmbPaymentMethods.DisplayMember = "code";
    cmbPaymentMethods.ValueMember = "code";
```

I shall thankful for any advice.

Kishore

Comment: "not working" doesn't tell us anything about what you're seeing. Do you have a compile-time error? An execution time error? Is the new item just not being shown? (I've added an answer using psychic debugging, but please write a more detailed question next time...)

Comment: Sorry Jon, not working I mean to say that not giving desired output. No compile or runtime error.

Comment: Right. In that case see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suspect this builds but doesn't show the extra item. That's because you're adding the new item to a "temporary" list that you throw away, and then you're building a *new* list for the data source.

You want to call `ToList()` just once, and use that list for both insertion and the data source:

```
var itemsList = items.ToList();
itemsList.Insert(0, new { code = string.Empty }); // Or use Add for the end...

cmbPaymentMethods.DataSource = itemsList;
```

Comment: @kishorebarik If it worked, you may want to accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

items.ToList() will return a new instance of the object, so the item is being added into a new list, which is not the one you want.

Everytime you have "items.ToList()" a new instance will be created. You would need to have:

```
var list =  items.ToList();

list.Add(new { code = string.Empty });

cmbPaymentMethods.DataSource = list;
```

Comment: Uppss... sorry, it looks like someone was faster writing the answer than me!

Comment: But, your trick is fullproof, Yumei. I just created another var type variable as your advice then added the empty item. And this worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

how to use  XNamespace ns = xDocItems.Root.Name.Namespace;
    var items =
    from i in
    xDocItems.Descendants(ns + "insync_navpaymentmethods")
    select new
    {
        code = (string)i.Element(ns + "Code"),

Comment: I am sorry user3359294, I could not understand what do you mean?